# Change Combobox.ScrollBarAlign property in vba programatically at runtime

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can anyone tell me how to change Combobox.ScrollBarAlign property in ms access vba at runtime, I tried that in property sheet mode and it's working but I want do that at runtime.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196571(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: brax, I tried that at runtime but property value it still same design value and not changed

Comment: for example if the property value in design mode 2 "left" and try to change it at runtime to 1 "right" it will still 2 "left" and not occurs any error, what do you think that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation seems to be incomplete / misleading on this.

This is a property that can only be set at **design time** (in Design View), not at runtime.

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=139578